# How to display date and time in Meteor by creating a template helper?

Tags: javascript, datetime, meteor, meteor-helper

How should i display the date and time on web page by using template helper.Here is the code i wrote but it does not work.
I wrote the {{display_time}} part in html and javascript. I think display_time helper part is correct but i don't know how to render it in html.

**Js file**

```
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Session.get('counter');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
    }
  });
  Template.display_time.helpers({
    datelist:function(){
      var begin = new Date();
      return Session.get('time');

    }
  });
}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

**html file**

```
<head>
  <title>my_first_app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello from Me</h1>

  {{> hello}}
  {{> display_time}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>
<template name = "display_time">
  <p>The time now is:{{time}}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you mean `time: function(){` instead of `datelist :function(){`?

Comment: No. Is there any time function that displays time.

Comment: I solved the problem using **MomentJs** package.